# How to convert object detection application in exe, by using openvino optimized model and YOLO

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

When I use this commend `pyinstaller main.py --onefile -w` to convert the project to exe file, I get this problem:

```
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''C:\Users\sachin\Appdata\Local\Temp\_MEI177322\ultralytics\yolo\cfg\default.yaml.
```